# script for copying directories with particular increment

Tags: shell-script, directory, cp

I have directories which are named as 0.1, 0.15,0.2, 0.25, 0.3,0.35 and so on.
Now I want to copy directories at particular increments say of 0.1 together to a separate directory.
Say directories 0.1,0.2,0.3 should go to folder one; directories 0.15,0.25,0.35 should go to folder two, etc. How can I do it with ease?

Answer (score 2):

For your specific problem you can use the length of the file names to distinguish them:

```
mv ??? first
mv ???? second
```

If you want to solve this in a more general case you really want to use a language like Python or Ruby, where looping over files and basic arithmetic are sane.

Comment: In case we get to `10.1`, your patterns should probably be `*.?` and `*.??`, or, bash-specific, `shopt -s extglob; mv +([0-9]).[0-9] first`

Answer (score 0):

If your shell support [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

for the first increment:

`mv /path/to/0.{0..99} /path/to/newdirectory/`

the second increment:

`mv /path/to/0.{0..99}5 /path/to/newdir/`

note: change `0` and `99` from `{0..99}` with first and last digit of your increment.

Answer (score -1):

This is the directory structure I am using

```
/
--0.1 - file
--0.2 - file
--0.15 - file
--0.25 - file
--first - dir
--second - dir
```

Now, first I will  move the 0.1 and 0.2 files into dir 'first'

```
for f in `ls|grep '^0\.[0-9]$'`;do;mv $f first;done;
```

Next I'll move the 0.15 and 0.25 into dir 'second'

```
for f in `ls|grep '^0\.[0-9][0-9]$'`;do;mv $f second;done
```

In the code, `grep '<regex>'` lists all the files matching the pattern and then mv moves them to the respective directories.